# How to format dates in different cultures like English, German and Italy

Tags: extjs

I wanted to format dates in different culture as stated above in Ext Js where i have created one method setDateFormat which accept dateformat "d"(ShortDateFormat) this needs to be formatted in different cultures so for this what code is required in Ext Js, please let me know.

Comment: Do you guys know any function in Extjs which detects the language set in browser?

Answer (score 0):

For formatting dates in Ext JS you can use [`Ext.util.Format.date()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.util.Format-method-date) method.

As first parameter to this method you will pass date which you want to format and as second parameter date format string.

List of valid format strings and date formatting examples you can find in documentation of [`Ext.Date`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.Date) class

Comment: even i need to know browser langugae in Extjs way